# Create Ract App build includes unused libraries and unused components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, build, create-react-app

I ran an analyzer on my production build, and there is weird xlsx(cpexcel.js) and moment.js library that I've not used anywhere in my App's code, also I am using react-rainbow library, though I have only imported only a few of components from there(Navbar), in the build, Whole library is included.

see source-map-explorer picture:

[image]

How can I make production build exclude these unused libraries and unused components?

Comment: I knew Webpack does this automatically leveraging a feature called "tree shaking" when you use ES6 imports and your code is side-effect free (does not modify the global scope), which indeed is the case with projects bootstrapped with `create-react-app`... Reading your answer makes me think that this is not true...

Comment: @tonix as a workaorund, is there way to make this manually? Also, how do I exclude excel library from my build? Not sure why react adds it automatically in build.

Comment: Don't really know, would need to investigate. If I'll come up with something, I will write an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project's root folder and run

```
npx depcheck
```

It will display all the unused packages in your project.

To uninstall a module simply run the below command

```
npm uninstall <package>
```